# salesforce app developed using Aura not working in IE11 compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, salesforce, babeljs

I have written some es6 syntax on our components and since IE is not fully compatible with es6 I was wondering what is the best way to automatically transpile these components to es5, does salesforce provide something out of box for this?

For ex we have following code into our component:

```
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".items div");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) elems[i].classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("yourFeed").classList.add("active");

    var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:DraggableNavEvent");
    appEvent.setParams({ feedType: "yourFeed" });
    appEvent.fire();
```

I would want this to be transpiled to es6 where all he conts are converted to var. Can I also use any tool that does all this job before deploying to salesforce? I read about babel but not sure how to integrate with salesforce project!

Comment: I'd suggest getting started with babel. This question it probably to broad but as your using typescript google for somethig like: `babel with typescript`. Maybe take a look at this link: https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/

Comment: You can use npm and gulp for this task. For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-typescript or https://www.npmjs.com/package/Babel